# global lock causing my program to stop running

Tags: python, python-3.x, locking, python-multithreading

Whenever I run part of my program that has a `threading.Lock` in it, my program stops running altogether (It does not crash, just pauses).

I need this as it is a server and multiple clients may be connecting and trying to overwrite the data all at the same time. At the time of running this, only one thread was active with a client connecting to it. I use this for my Sqlite3 databases too. I have not noticed it causing a problem there, as it seems to run perfectly fine despite the global lock. All are done in the same format of

```
with global_lock:
```

Here is where the thread starts alongside how I import the thread

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
global_lock = Lock()
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    connThread = Thread(target=handler, args=(conn, addr))
    connThread.daemon = True
    connThread.start()
```

Here is the program

```
def addUser_InHash(username, password):

    print("Adding user in hash")
    hashID = 0
    hashString = username + password
    added = False
    for i in hashString:
        hashID += ord(i)
    hashID = hashID % hashKey
    print(hashID, "hashID in addUser")

    file = open("LoginHashTable.pickle", "rb+")
    if os.path.getsize("LoginHashTable.pickle") > 0:
        hashTable = pickle.load(file)
        print("File not empty,\nSaved Data:\n{}".format(hashTable))

    else:
        print("File empty")
        hashTable = {}
    count = 0

    while not added:
        print("while not count :", count)
        count += 1
        if hashID in hashTable:
            # If this index exists
            if hashID > (hashKey - 1):
                hashID = 0
            else:
                hashID += 1
                if hashID > (hashKey - 1):
                    hashID = 0

        else:
            print("User doesnt exist, adding to hash table")
            hashTable[hashID] = [username, password]
            print("New Added")
            print(hashTable)
            added = True

    print("Saving updated file addUser_InHash")

    if hashTable:
        with global_lock:
            file.seek(0)  # Move file pointer back to beginning of file
            file.truncate()  # Empty file by truncating to current file pointer position
            pickle.dump(hashTable, file)
            print(hashTable)
            print("Data saved")
            file.close()
    else:
        print("Hash table still empty, addUser_InHash")


def deleteUser_InHash(username, password):


    print("In deleteUser_InHash\nUsername: {}\nPassword: {}".format(username,password))
    dataFound = True
    hashID = 0
    count = 0
    hashString = username + password

    if os.path.getsize("LoginHashTable.pickle") > 0:
        file = open("LoginHashTable.pickle", "rb+")
        hashTable = pickle.load(file)
        print("File not empty,\nSaved Data:\n{}".format(hashTable))

    else:
        print("File empty")
        dataFound = False

    if dataFound:
        print("datafound true")
        for i in hashString:
            hashID += ord(i)
        hashID = hashID % hashKey
        print("hashID:",hashID)
        try:
            print("In try")
            while dataFound:
                print("In while, count:",count)
                if count == hashKey:
                    dataFound = False
                if hashTable[hashID] == [username,password]:
                    del hashTable[hashID]
                    print("Outside global lock")
                    with global_lock:
                        print("Inside global lock")
                        file.seek(0)  # Move file pointer back to beginning of file
                        file.truncate()  # Empty file by truncating to current file pointer position
                        pickle.dump(hashTable, file)
                        print(hashTable)
                        print("Data saved")
                        file.close()
                    print("Outside global lock")
                    print("Data updated")
                    print("User :", username, "deleted")
                    break
                else:
                    hashID += 1
                count += 1

        except IndexError:
            print("username could not be found")
            return False

    else:
        return False
```

The two functions are called in this sequence:

```
deleteUser_InHash(username1,password1)
addUser_InHash(username2,password2)
```

The with global lock works fine in `deleteUser_InHash()` function but stops the program in `addUser_InHash()`.

The program hangs here:

```
{33: ['foo', 'bar'], 0: ['toni', 'tony'], 34: ['bar', 'foo'], 118: ['fo', 'la'], 8: ['Tom', 'Tom'], 262: ['Kam', 'Kam'], 258: ['yes', 'no']}
Saving updated file addUser_InHash
```

Hanging on the line the piece of code:

```
if hashTable:
    with global_lock:
```

I know this is true as it never gets to the print statements:

```
print(hashTable)
print("Data saved")
```

Inside "addUser_InHash()"

Comment: Do you know where it's hanging?

Comment: I have edited it in

Comment: That helps, but I meant on exactly what line. You also need to add the code that starts the two threads running. It's possible that they are deadlocking (both waiting for the `Lock` to be released—but I can't for sure tell yet.

Comment: Only one thread is running at the time of me testing this code

Comment: If only one function is running, then a `with global_lock:` will always work and therefore not cause the program to hang (since two threads could not be trying to acquire the `Lock` at the same time).

Comment: Where is the `global_lock` variable defined?

Comment: @martineau I have edited the post again, as I said, i know something is going wrong inside the "with global_lock" part as I have a print statement before it: "Saving updated file addUser_InHash" and two print statement inside the "with global_lock" which are never reached

Comment: There are two `with global lock:` statement in the posted code. Unless more than one thread is running, using it will never hang the program—so there must be some other issue. You need to make the code in your question runnable so others can reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That code is not going to be simple in the slightest. It requires a very large portion of my code.

Comment: @martineau should I make a new thread? or should I just edit this one?

Comment: James: Might be cleaner to ask a new question and just delete this one... In the new question, just to put in just enough code to reproduce the problem so there's not a bunch of code that has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Will try my best, thank you for the support

Comment: @martineau Okay so I thought I would reply to you again giving you an update, I found that using "RLock" instead of "Lock" solved the problem, i do not know why. Maybe you do?

Comment: That's good to hear. Couldn't say why with certainty without seeing more of the code involved. The basic difference between the two kinds of `Lock`s is what happens when the same process tries to acquire one again without an intervening release. With a regular `Lock` the process will block at that point which prevents anything further from getting done—including releasing the `Lock`. This is so-called [_deadlock_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock). In a nutshell using `RLock`s avoids that problem because they don't block in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Note to all: I changed

```
global_lock = Lock()
```

to

```
global_lock = RLock()
```

and now my program is running fine, I believe it has something to do with the fact that RLock allows threads to re-acquire a lock more than once, whilst it seems that normal locks cannot?

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects